# Why swap file is never used?

Tags: 18.04, swap

Even when memory is fully loaded, the swap file I created is never used.

Did I do something wrong ?

Output for `swapon -s`

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority 
/file.swap              file        15728636    0   -2
```

Output for `cat /etc/fstab`

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
# Entry for /swapfile
/file.swap none swap defaults 0 0
```

Output for `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

```
60
```

### **EDIT**

Output for `free -h`

[image]

As you can see, I reduced the size of the swap file by half and it finally started to be used when memory got fully loaded instead of starting at 40% of memory used (according to swappiness). I don't have no problem anymore, now I'm just trying to understand the swapfile behaviour.

Additional info : I ran simultaneously 80 Firefox instances to get this result.

Comment: please update your question with the output of `free -h` .. taken when you fill that the system is using up memory without swapping.

Comment: it will take me 4 hours to reproduce it but i will give free -h today, thanks

Comment: The only time my computer seems to use swap is when hybernating. The ability to hybernate is important to me.

Comment: I edited my post, now out of curiosity, I'm wondering why it wasn't used before

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swap is used in this cases (well, +1 if you count hibernation):

- Your system runs out of RAM and needs to swap out currently unused parts to make place for currently used parts. If you have enough RAM that your workload fits completely into it this won't happen.
- The system determines that a task is idle for very long times and the memory it uses can better be used for caching. This mostly happens on long running systems which tasks that only run occasionally. An example would be an always running mail-client that checks for mail every few hours, but does nothing in between.
- Some high-memory programs still might go to swap (video and 3d editors, math tools), but for the most part it will only be there if needed.

It seems that neither is the case for you, so no need to worry. A problem would be if neither is the case but the system would still be hitting swap.

Also, if you have about 8+ GB of RAM, swap is only needed for hibernation. Swap partition will be never used if your computer has 8+ GB RAM and you shutdown it every day no swap is needed and it is normal.

Comment: How much swap memory should there be? In a video, the guy said ram*underroot two (1.4 something), and I have 8 GB of RAM and 11. GB of Swap. i never have seen swap used, shold i just not allocate more space.